# Show that an infinite Integral equals an infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Show that $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\text{sin} ax}{e^x-1} dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a}{n^2+a^2}$$

My classmate asked me this problem and I don't know how to prove it. I guess that it can be proved by a clever use of Fubini's Theorem, but I'm just not clever enough. Can anyone help?

Comment: Seems like an application of the residue theorem.

Comment: Just use euler identity then series- expand the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

First, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin ax}{e^x - 1} dx &= \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sin ax \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sin ax \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-nx} dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sin ax \cdot e^{-nx} dx
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Let 
\begin{equation}
M_n = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sin ax \cdot e^{-nx} dx,
\end{equation}
and next we try to compute $M_n$.
Obviously, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
M_n &= -\frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sin ax \, de^{-nx} \\
&= -\frac{1}{n} (- \int_{0}^{+\infty} a \cos ax \cdot e^{-nx} dx) \\
&= -\frac{a}{n^2} (\int_{0}^{+\infty} a \cos ax \, de^{-nx}) \\
&=  -\frac{a}{n^2} (-1 + a M_n).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Thus 
\begin{equation}
M_n = \frac{a}{n^2 + a^2}.
\end{equation}